# problem retrieving file from request.FILES

Tags: python, django, request

I have this at django

```
@csrf_exempt  
@require_http_methods(['POST'])  
@api_token  
def foo(request):
    upload_file = request.FILES['file']
    random_function(upload_file)
    return HttpResponse('done')
```

and this at another python file

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/external/path"

payload = {}
files = {'file': open('csv_file.csv', 'rb')}
headers = {
    'x-api-key': 'api-key-token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

the problem is that  when I executed the python file I got this error

`django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file'`

it was like `request.FILES` can't find `file` name
but when I execute it from postman it works fine

Comment: Have you tried `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` instead?

Comment: I've tried it but still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I've tried

```
headers = {
    'x-api-key': 'api-key-token'
}
```

And then it works. My team said because the boundary has gone missing since we force the content type to be `multipart/form-data` but I still don't quite get it yet. If anyone can explain it would be much appreciated